# Role based authorization using AWS Cognito for a front end app

Tags: angular, session, authorization, token

How to implement role based authorization using Cognito user pool? Building a front end Angular app, I use Cognito user pool for authentication. No issue there. I want users with different roles to see different parts of the app. So a role needs to be brought back from somewhere. 
    I assigned a role to the user when the user is created in the user pool, and that role info can be brought back during authentication. I then use this role to make decision what UI pages to show for the current authenticated user (like in auth guard using CanActivate etc in Angular). 
    This only works to some extent, because the user role cannot survive a F5 refresh or user routes to another page by typing in URL directly (which causes the page to re-load). 
    This user role info needs to be stored in the token or user session somehow so we can retrieve the user role as long as the user session is valid. Does anyone know how? Is there an example somewhere? Searched, see some talk about using AWS IAM policy, user groups in Cognito etc, but cannot figure it out.

```
Thanks a lot for looking,
```

Martin

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me answer my own question. 
Figured out one way. Turns out AWS Cognito keeps the user related info (whatever you included in the user pool when created) in the id token. So if I designed a field to serve as the user role, I can retrieve anytime after sign in as long as the session is still valid. So to control access to certain page, I just need to check if the user is authenticated and its role matches what's expected (using CanActivate).

It works pretty well to me, but I'm not 100% sure if there is any inherent security risk by using Cognito for both authentication and authorization. Please let me know if you know any and how to avoid it.